# Cannot import Mysql 5.7 dump with Chinese varchar(128) in Mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysqlpp

My Mysql5.7 database contains a restaurant menu with Chinese characters. I want to update to a newer Linux with a new database. This year I tried several times to update for Ubuntu 20 and MySQL 8.0, but all Chinese characters are wrong and don't look Chinese at all.

I am using libmysql++ in C++ to use in my software. Since the program is working in Ubuntu 18 and in Ubuntu only has wrong database characters I don't suspect the program. Also, I can show the program itself with Chinese ttf files, so only the menu card is wrong.

I see many issues in Stackoverflow with MySQL, is this still reliable to use?

If there is any way to make Linux Mysql 8.0 compatible with 5.7 then it would be great. Preferable in a /etc/mysql/configuration file.

What I do to import menu cards is : mysql -u user -ppassword, create database x, use x, source filename.sql

Comment: The problem could be in how the new database was defined, how the tables in that database were defined, and what encoding the *connection* between your software and the database is using. Is there a reason you don't use mysqldump to copy the old db and then the mysql command-line client to import that into the new?

Comment: I found out in a specific PC, that using the mysql does not work but an excel file with Chinese import works like a charm. Now I don't know what I did to get that situation.